# Install "AnimAll" Addon with python

Tags: python, animation, scripting, add-on, panel

I'm running a python script outside of Blender GUI using the bpy module.
For my code I need the "animAll" add-on from Blender, but I get an error when I try to enable it.

It seems that blender tries to look for the gui to add the panel...

Is there a way to disable 3D Viewport or is it not possible to run this add-on without GUI?

the link to the repro:
https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/animation_animall.py

**Code:**

```
import addon_utils
addon_utils.enable("animation_animall")
```

**Error:**

```
[animation_animall]
AnimAll: Updating Panel locations has failed

Error:

'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "animation_animall" not found'
Exception in module unregister(): '/home/blender/blender-git/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/3.0/scripts/addons/animation_animall.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/blender/blender-git/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/3.0/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 439, in disable
mod.unregister()
File "/home/blender/blender-git/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/3.0/scripts/addons/animation_animall.py", line 581, in unregister
bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_animall)
RuntimeError: unregister_class(...):, missing bl_rna attribute from 'RNAMeta' instance (may not be registered)
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 26368, total unfreed memory 8.083801 MB
```

Comment: Nor sure but I guess you need to import the module that contains the 'RNAMeta' instance

Comment: @DGRL  hmm.. do you know what this module actually does or where i can find it? Maybe blender coudn't already register the VIEW3D_PT_animall class and therfore this class can't be unregisterd?

Comment: How about "'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "animation_animall" not found'" 

What key is this?